# How to get Tensorflow Served model to pull from passed in input and not local batch file?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am currently trying to get seq2seq model working with TF Serving. I thought I had it correctly however it seems I was mistaken. I originally trained the model via local text file input, read in as batches.  Now I want to have a passed in sentence and it return back to me the summation.

I have been successful in getting the model saved, served and now I am able to view the prediction on my front end page, however the result is still pulling from my local text file and not my passed in query param sentence.

My input is one sentence currently sent as a query param, but the result actually displayed is pulling from my text file still, even though I mapped batch_x to the value of my arg[1] which I have verified is the correct expected input.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Clearly I have misunderstood the process I was supposed to take.

Now an important note to make here is that if I modify the value of the argument passed in and call the python file directly, I get the correct results.  However when I make the same call to the frozen model being served, I always get the same prediction response regardless of what is sent in.

This is how I am freezing the model (Notice the mapping of inputs_dict.X to batch_x...believe the issue is something I am doing here incorrectly):

```
pickle_fn = 'args.pickle'
folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/pickle'
pickle_filepath = os.path.join(folder, pickle_fn)
with open(pickle_filepath, "rb") as f:
    args = pickle.load(f)

print("Loading dictionary...")
word_dict, reversed_dict, article_max_len, summary_max_len = build_dict("valid", args.toy)
print("Loading validation dataset...")

#The below call will pull from the arg passed when "serve" is used
valid_x, valid_y = build_dataset("serve", word_dict, article_max_len, summary_max_len, args.toy)
valid_x_len = list(map(lambda x: len([y for y in x if y != 0]), valid_x))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print("Loading saved model...")
    model = Model(reversed_dict, article_max_len, summary_max_len, args, forward_only=True)
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state("./saved_model/")
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)

    batches = batch_iter(valid_x, valid_y, args.batch_size, 1)
    #print(valid_x, file=open("art_working_inp.txt", "a"))
    print("Writing summaries to 'result.txt'...")
    for batch_x, batch_y in batches:
        batch_x_len = list(map(lambda x: len([y for y in x if y != 0]), batch_x))

        valid_feed_dict = {
            model.batch_size: len(batch_x),
            model.X: batch_x,
            model.X_len: batch_x_len,
        }

        prediction = sess.run(model.prediction, feed_dict=valid_feed_dict)
        prediction_output = list(map(lambda x: [reversed_dict[y] for y in x], prediction[:, 0, :]))

        #Save out our model
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        path = os.path.join(cwd, 'simple')

        inputs_dict = {
            "X": tf.convert_to_tensor(batch_x)
        }
        outputs_dict = {
            "prediction": tf.convert_to_tensor(prediction_output)
        }

        tf.saved_model.simple_save(
            sess, path, inputs_dict, outputs_dict
        )
        print('Model Saved')
        #End save model code

        #Save results to file
        with open("result.txt", "a") as f:
            for line in prediction_output:
                summary = list()
                for word in line:
                    if word == "</s>":
                        break
                    if word not in summary:
                        summary.append(word)
                print(" ".join(summary), file=f)

    print('Summaries are saved to "result.txt"...')
```

Then my call to the server for inference is here. Regardless of what I put into data, it will always spit out the same prediction which is the one I originally passed in when exporting the model.

```
def do_inference(hostport):
  """Tests PredictionService with concurrent requests.
  Args:
    hostport: Host:port address of the PredictionService.
  Returns:
    pred values, ground truth labels, processing time 
  """
  # connect to server
  host, port = hostport.split(':')
  channel = grpc.insecure_channel(hostport)
  stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)

  # prepare request object 
  request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
  request.model_spec.name = 'saved_model'

  # Get the input data from our arg
  jsn_inp = sys.argv[1] 
  data = json.loads(jsn_inp)['tokenized']
  data = np.array(data)

  request.inputs['X'].CopyFrom(
      tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(data, shape=data.shape, dtype=tf.int64))

  #print(request)
  result = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)  # 10 seconds

  return result
```

Should this be of any use, this is how it is building the dataset. I modified the build_dataset function so it uses just the arg passed in, but this didnt resolve the problem either. I thought perhaps something similar to javascript closures was occuring or something, so I thought I would pull the data in this way.

```
def build_dataset(step, word_dict, article_max_len, summary_max_len, toy=False):
    if step == "train":
        article_list = get_text_list(train_article_path, toy)
        title_list = get_text_list(train_title_path, toy)
    elif step == "valid":
        article_list = get_text_list(valid_article_path, toy)
        title_list = get_text_list(valid_title_path, toy)
    elif step == "serve":
        arg_to_use = sys.argv[1] if ("tokenized" in sys.argv[1]) else sys.argv[2]
        article_list = [json.loads(arg_to_use)["tokenized"]]
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError
    if step != "serve":
        x = list(map(lambda d: word_tokenize(d), article_list))
        x = list(map(lambda d: list(map(lambda w: word_dict.get(w, word_dict["<unk>"]), d)), x))
        x = list(map(lambda d: d[:article_max_len], x))
        x = list(map(lambda d: d + (article_max_len - len(d)) * [word_dict["<padding>"]], x))
        print(x, file=open("input_values.txt", "a"))
        y = list(map(lambda d: word_tokenize(d), title_list))
        y = list(map(lambda d: list(map(lambda w: word_dict.get(w, word_dict["<unk>"]), d)), y))
        y = list(map(lambda d: d[:(summary_max_len-1)], y))
    else:
        x = article_list
        #x = list(map(lambda d: word_tokenize(d), article_list))
        #x = list(map(lambda d: list(map(lambda w: word_dict.get(w, word_dict["<unk>"]), d)), x))
        x = list(map(lambda d: d[:article_max_len], x))
        x = list(map(lambda d: d + (article_max_len - len(d)) * [word_dict["<padding>"]], x))
        y = list()

    return x, y
```

SignatureDef info (One thing that has me a bit concerned is the Const below...but not sure that is anything...going to be looking at that right now):

```
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['X'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (1, 50)
        name: Const:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['prediction'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (1, 11)
        name: Const_1:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Comment: are you sure this is a good way to export model for TF Serving. I need a model generated by seq2seq to support TF Serving. Could I follow your approach? Also refer [this](https://github.com/google/seq2seq/issues/114) and [this](https://github.com/google/seq2seq/issues/296#issuecomment-462735200) please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok....so it seems the const issue was my problem or rather directed me to finding what the real issue was.  The real source to my problem was that I was passing into tf.convert_to_tensor my values rather than the tf.placeholders themselves.  Therefore, by modifying the logic to the below entries when saving out the model, I was able to get the proper response when sending my inputs in. As you can see I also had to feed in the other original batch_size and x_len as well.  Hope others find this helpful.

```
inputs_dict = {
            "batch_size": tf.convert_to_tensor(model.batch_size),
            "X": tf.convert_to_tensor(model.X),
            "X_len": tf.convert_to_tensor(model.X_len),
        }
        outputs_dict = {
            "prediction": tf.convert_to_tensor(model.prediction)
        }
```

This yielded a much better looking SignatureDef:

```
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['X'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, 50)
        name: Placeholder:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['prediction'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, 10, -1)
        name: decoder/decoder/transpose_1:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```